# SQL Join with Multiple Conditions Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query with a `LEFT JOIN` and 3 conditions.  However, it's not working correctly and I'm getting more than 2x the results I should be.  The `[tmp_Address]` and `[tmp_City]` tables have the same 3324 rows, but when I run the query I end up with 6994 results.

I've narrowed it down to the actual join, but I can't see what I'm missing.  I have the three key fields from each set to each other, and I'm using AND within the ON, so I don't understand why it's not working.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST( ta.   [Company] AS varchar(10) )          AS [Company], 
    CAST( ta.   [Customer_Number] AS varchar(255) ) AS [ID], 
    CAST( ta.   [Ship_Number] AS varchar(255) )     AS [ID2], 
    CAST( ta.   [Name] AS varchar(255) )            AS [Name], 
    CAST( ta.   [Address1] AS varchar(255) )        AS [Address1], 
    CAST( ta.   [Address2] AS varchar(255) )        AS [Address2], 
    CAST( tc.   [City] AS varchar(100) )            AS [City], 
    CAST( ta.   [cleanCity] AS varchar(100) )       AS [cleanCity],
    CAST( tc.   [Confirmed] AS bit)                 AS [City_Confirmed] 
    FROM [tmp_address] ta
    LEFT JOIN [tmp_City] tc ON (
        tc.[Company]            = ta.[Company] AND 
        tc.[Customer_Number]    = ta.[Customer_Number] AND 
        tc.[Ship_Number]        = ta.[Ship_Number]  
        
    )
```

Here is data from the two tables:

```
[tmp_Address]
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
|Company    |Customer_Number    |Ship_Number    |Name                   |Address1                   |Address2               |cleanCity      |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
|SWS        |FP5996             |FP5996         |4FRONT - CARROLLTON    |SOLUTIONS                  |1612 HUTTON DR         |CARROLLTON     |
|SWS        |FP3980             |FP3980         |4FRONT ENGINEERED      |9800 INTERNATIONAL BOULEVA |NULL                   |PHARR          |
|SWS        |002060             |002060         |A & I PRODUCTS         |432 RAILWAY ST             |ALTONA, MANITOBA       |CANADA         |
|SWS        |006962             |006962         |AH STOCK MFG CORP      |8402 CTR RD                |NULL                   |NEWTON         |
|SWS        |FP6581             |FP6581         |AJ FORSYTH             |830 CARLISLE RDS PARK      |ANNACIS BUSINESS PARK  |NEW WESTMINSTE |

[tmp_City]
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|Company    |Customer_Number    |Ship_Number    |Original       |Orig_cleanCity |City       |Confirmed  |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|SWS        |002060             |002060         |CANADA         |CANADA         |CANADA     |1          |
|SWS        |FP5996             |FP5996         |CARROLLTON     |CARROLLTON     |CARROLLTON |1          |
|SWS        |FP6581             |FP6581         |NEW WESTMINSTE |NEW WESTMINSTE |DELTA      |0          |
|SWS        |006962             |006962         |NEWTON         |NEWTON         |NEWTON     |1          |
|SWS        |FP3980             |FP3980         |PHARR          |PHARR          |PHARR      |1          |
```

I am expecting a 1-to-1 match, so it should end up like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|Company    |Customer_Number    |Ship_Number    |Name                   |Address1                   |Address2               |cleanCity      |Original       |Orig_cleanCity |City       |Confirmed  |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|SWS        |FP5996             |FP5996         |4FRONT - CARROLLTON    |SOLUTIONS                  |1612 HUTTON DR         |CARROLLTON     |CARROLLTON     |CARROLLTON     |CARROLLTON |1          |
|SWS        |FP3980             |FP3980         |4FRONT ENGINEERED      |9800 INTERNATIONAL BOULEVA |NULL                   |PHARR          |PHARR          |PHARR          |PHARR      |1          |
|SWS        |002060             |002060         |A & I PRODUCTS         |432 RAILWAY ST             |ALTONA, MANITOBA       |CANADA         |CANADA         |CANADA         |CANADA     |1          |
|SWS        |006962             |006962         |AH STOCK MFG CORP      |8402 CTR RD                |NULL                   |NEWTON         |NEWTON         |NEWTON         |NEWTON     |1          |
|SWS        |FP6581             |FP6581         |AJ FORSYTH             |830 CARLISLE RDS PARK      |ANNACIS BUSINESS PARK  |NEW WESTMINSTE |NEW WESTMINSTE |NEW WESTMINSTE |DELTA      |0          |
```

Yes, I know there are lots of similar questions, and the answers say to put the multiple conditions after the ON, which I did...  So...

Comment: Is `(Company, Customer_Number, Ship_Number)` unique in both tables?  If not, that's the source of the problem.  `SELECT Company, Customer_Number, Ship_Number, COUNT(*) FROM each_table GROUP BY Company, Customer_Number, Ship_Number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` to find the issues.  Feel free to `[quote]` the column names if required.

Comment: See the following: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09b2aac4f0adbac233a84bc452f1db9b

Comment: Correction in the fiddle above.  You'll need to provide the problem data to show the issue.  The above had no issues.  But the query I showed in the above comment will identify any data issues.

Comment: @JonArmstrong OMG, the client added HUNDREDS of dupes to the file!
Thank you, I made the assumption that the client actually dedupped like they told me they did.

Comment: "If I had a dollar for every time a client said they did (or didn't do) something that later turned out to be untrue ... " ;-)